# Please recommend a good JQuery rich text editor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What is a good JQuery rich text editing field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've recently been seriously scared off tinyMCE after trying to write some plugins for it and finding it very, very frustrating.

Currently my suggestion would be the latest version of [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) it seems much cleaner, accessible and looks a little easier for writing plugins.

I know [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/) are also working on theirs activily at the moment, trying to make is more accessible too, so that might be a decent option.

Either way, I'd pass on tinymce to be honest.

I know you're asking for a jquery specific one, but the question doesn't make a lot of sense to be honest. JQuery, as good as it is at some things, is not going to be much specific help at the basic level of developing a rich text area - you're much better off looking at the ones that have been built individually and selecting the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: I like tinymce because it's well integrated and the users are used to it. I'm using Ruby on rails and there's a plugin especially for it so... but yeah your point is valid

Comment: is tinyMCE free for using commercial purpose on a website ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say use [tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) that you can use as a [jQuery plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_23.php).

Comment: is tinyMCE free for using commercial purpose on a website ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best one which i have used and tested which works with even jquery 1.7 Simple and easy when compared to others.  [Cazary](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2015/05/cazary-jquery-plugin-of-wysiwyg-editor/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of 14 really amazing jQuery and non-jQuery rich text editors (RTE). They are all free, easy to use, and with great functionality. Enjoy.

http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/14-jquery-and-non-jquery-rich-text-editors/